# Gibbs free energy and heat capacity in constant volume

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to know if one can find the heat capacity in constant volume from the Gibb's free energy:

$G= U + PV - TS$

$$C_v=T\left(\frac {\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}$$.

From the Maxwell relations I can write:

$$C_v=-T\left(\frac {\partial^2 F}{\partial T^2}\right)_{V,N}$$.

Is it possible to express the heat capacity (for constant volume/pressure) from other thermodynamical potentials ?

In case of the Gibbs free energy, if I express it as $G= F + PV$ would it be a correct thing to do, even though G is not a function of volume like F (Helmholtz energy).

Comment: $S$ is also $-(\partial G/\partial T)_{P,N}$, so $C_V=-T\partial/\partial T[(\partial G/\partial T)_{P,N}]_{V,N}$.  Is this what you’re asking about?

Comment: Yes, I was able to derive it, thank you